# [gmail-api]How to get count of Primary Category

Tags: gmail-api

How to get the count of the primary category in the gmail inbox. We can get for other categories like social by adding the label id CATEGORY_SOCIAL in the get label api call, but there seems to be no label id 'CATEGORY_PRIMARY'.

There is a CATEGORY_PERSONAL, is it same as primary?

Answer (score 0):

CATEGORY_PERSONAL is not the same as the “Primary” category. The Method: `users.labels.get` only works for labels which is different from categories. Labels are located at the left of your Gmail inbox and categories are at the top. The other categories are listed in [types of labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#types_of_labels) because labels for those categories are automatically created. Since the “Primary” category doesn’t have a label, you can’t retrieve the information with `users.labels.get`.

There is another way to retrieve information for categories, which is [Method: users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) with parameters: `userId = user's email address`, `maxResults = 500`, `q = category:primary`, however, maximum of messages to return is 500 and you only get an estimated total number of results.

Getting data for Gmail categories, is a product limitation for Gmail API, this request can be promoted for future development through [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support#missing_features).

CATEGORY_PERSONAL was part from the now discontinued ["Inbox by Gmail"](https://gmail.google.com/inbox/).